# best textbooks for difficult specialist maths questions in year 11

Tags: self-learning

I am currently studying year 11 specialist maths in Western Australia and I am doing the O.T. Lee textbook, however, I am looking for harder questions that will properly challenge my conceptual understanding of the topic.
These are the topics being studied: combinatorics, geometry, trigonometry, complex
numbers, vectors, matrices, calculus and statistics, as well as proofs.
What textbooks will provide challenging questions that are on par with the difficulty of exams or even harder. This is because I want to improve on the very challenging questions that I've never seen before so that I can adapt to different questions during tests and exams questions and ultimately improve my results as well as obtaining greater understanding of the topic. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

there are numberless textbooks and books on these subjects but if you are a high school student and you are interested in hard challenges I recommend the following.

**combinatorics:**

- *Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics* by CHEN

**geometry:**

- *Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads* by Evan Chen

for **proof writing book** reference check [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62629/textbook-recommendations-for-undergraduate-proof-writing-class)
.

Comment: would these books help me with school maths

Comment: both of them are easily readable and have lots of exercises, first one also has a complete manual solution.